# How to create a function of a type f(*args)(X) in Python?

Tags: python, function

I am writing a certain game solver. In the process i need to get estimates of the current game state with different estimator functions. Which can all come from the same family. Say, the function takes "game_state" as a main argument and returns a score. But it also has other parameters, say "depth" and "width".

This is probably very simple but i didn't manage to google the answer. I get links about "higher order functions in Python" or "decorators", but they don't help me. What I'd like to achieve is something like the following construction (if it's not possible, i will work around somehow) :

```
def main_func(something, estimator_function):
    return estimator_function(something)

def estimator_with_params(something, a, b):
    return something * a + b

something = 1
result = main_func(something, estimator_with_params(a=2, b=3))
print(number)
```

Of course, this produces:
TypeError: estimator_with_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'something'

Is there a simple way to rewrite it correctly?

Comment: `functools.partial()` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That was really simple. Thank you, @jasonharper !

```
def estimator(x, y):
    return functools.partial(estimator_with_params, a=x, b=y)
```

And it works just fine.